# How to create a custom class with multiple keys and objects like NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, list

I am a newbie to Objective C. I would like to create a class that has a nested class in it. To my knowledge, there is nothing like nested classes.
I would like it to be like an NSArray of NSMutableDictionary.

So far I have two different custom classes, where one is supposed to be nested in the other.

**Group.h**

```
#import "Category.h"
@interface Group : NSObject
- (instancetype)initWithGroupName:(NSString *)groupName
- (Category *)category;
@end
```

**Group.m**

```
@interface Group ()
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *groupName;
@end

@implementation Group
- (instancetype)initWithGroupName:(NSString *)groupName {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.groupName = groupName;
        self.payID = paymentID;
        self.sort = sortOrder;
    }
return self;
}

- (NSString *)name {
    return self.groupName;
}

- (Category *)category {
    Category *test = [[Category alloc] init];
    return test;
}
```

**Category.h**

```
@interface Category : NSObject
- (instancetype)initWithCategoryName:(NSString *)name 
                     withDescription:(NSString *)description 
                           ofPercent:(int)percent;
- (NSString *)name;
- (NSString *)description;
- (NSString *)percent;
@end
```

**Category.m**

```
@interface Category ()
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *title;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *descrip;
@property(assign) int perc;
@end

@implementation Category
- (instancetype)initWithCategoryName:(NSString *)name 
                     withDescription:(NSString *)description 
                           ofPercent:(int)percent {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.title = name;
        self.descrip = description;
        self.perc = percent;
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSString *)name {
    return self.title;
}

- (NSString *)description {
    return self.descrip;
}

- (NSString *)percent {
    return [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.perc * 100] stringByAppendingString:@"%"];
}
@end
```

I am not sure how to make it work. What exactly I want to do is to have one Group with many categories in it or one group that has 4 subgroups with many categories in each subgroups.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What do you mean by "nested classes"?

Comment: just to add: you are creating a custom getter , where you are calling another getter "self.title", you can just create -(NSString *)title , and return _title;

Comment: Then in Group, declare NSMutableArray *categoriesArray. Then you can add/remove categories object into this array.